# Why is the method output printed first?

Tags: ruby

I wrote the following:

```
greeting="i am awesome"
puts("I was saying that #{greeting}")
# => I was saying that i am awesome
```

When I change it to this:

```
def showman
  print("I am awesome ")
end
puts("I was saying that #{showman}")
# => I am awesome I was saying that
```

why is the method output printed first, and then the string? Why is it not printing like `"I was saying that I am awesome"`? What can I do to make the output be as such?

If I modify the `showman` function to:

```
def showman
  return ("I am awesome ")
end
```

then it gives the desired output. Why is the use of `return` in this way making difference to the output?

Comment: Try to understand that although `print` and `puts` print something to the screen, they always have a return value of `nil`. Check it out in irb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In first output why method output is printed first and then the string.

In order to evaluate the string, `showman` is evaluated before the whole string is evaluated, which prints `"I am awesome "`.

> Why its not printing like "I was saying that I am awesome"

Because `print` returns `nil`, and interpolating `nil` in a string evaluates to an empty string (`"#{showman}"` → `"#{nil}"` → `""`). Without `print`, the `showman` method returns the string `"I am awesome "`.

> Why is the use of return in this way making difference to the output?

It is not the use of `return` that is making the difference. It is the absence of `print` that is making the difference.